# c# Method not getting called

Tags: c#, methods

as the title says my method "Colors" is not getting called at multiple places i tried putting a break point but it just skip's the method and keep's going on and on here's the method code

```
void Colors(int start, int end, string name)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= 13; j++)
    {
        for (int p = start; p < end; p++)
        {
            if (Reserve[p].Contains("clubs"))
            {
                string a = j.ToString() + "_clubs";
                string b = j.ToString() + "-clubs";
                clubs++;
                if (Reserve[p].Contains(a) || Reserve[p].Contains(b))
                {
                    if (maxClubs <= j)
                    {
                        maxClubs = j;
                        if (Cvqt.Contains(maxClubs.ToString() + " " + "maxClub " + name))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Cvqt.Add(maxClubs + " " + "maxClub " + name);
                        }
                        if (Cvqt.Contains(clubs.ToString() + " " + "clubs" + name))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Cvqt.Add(clubs + " " + "clubs" + name);
                        }
                        /////////////////////////////
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here i call the method

```
async void Shuffle()
{
    bool check = false;
    Bitmap backImage = new Bitmap("Assets\\Back\\Back.png");
    int horizontal = 580, vertical = 480;
    Random r = new Random();
    for (i = ImgLocation.Length; i > 0; i--)
    {
        int j = r.Next(i);
        var k = ImgLocation[j];
        ImgLocation[j] = ImgLocation[i - 1];
        ImgLocation[i - 1] = k;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 17; i++)
    {
        Deck[i] = Image.FromFile(ImgLocation[i]);
        Reserve[i] = ImgLocation[i];
        Holder[i] = new PictureBox();
        Holder[i].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        Holder[i].Height = 130;
        Holder[i].Width = 80;
        this.Controls.Add(Holder[i]);
        Holder[i].Name = "pb" + i.ToString();
        await Task.Delay(200);
        if (i < 2)
        {
            Holder[i].Image = Deck[i];

            if (Holder[0].Tag != null)
            {
                Holder[1].Tag = Reserve[1];
            }
            Holder[0].Tag = Reserve[0];
            Holder[i].Location = new Point(horizontal, vertical);
            horizontal += Holder[i].Width;
            Colors(0, 1, "Player"); //it's just skipping this part here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly are you putting your break points?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but you should [avoid async void methods](http://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/)

Comment: whenever it enters the if (i < 2)

Comment: Have you put a break inside the Colors method?

Comment: @Assim - what happens when you comment out `Task.Delay()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just did Clean and Rebuild of the solution that did the job for me thanks to Ron Beyer for the quick answer ! Cheers..